# Writing UILabels in viewdidload Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c

Want i want to do is i get a number from a php script. This number determines the labels that have to be added to the view. The php script is very simple and is the following:

```
<?php

echo (int)5;

?>
```

The objc script has to determine the number and needs to write as many labels als the php script describes. I am showing the string in another label to be sure that the number is being returned. How do i write those labels to my view?

I got some code as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *post = @"";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://......./testGet.php"]];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSData *urlData; 
    NSURLResponse *response; 
    NSError *error;
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 
    if(!urlData) {
        NSLog(@"No connection!");
    }

    NSString *aStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease]; 


    int i;
    i = [aStr intValue];
    status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

    for (int i; i <= 10; i++)
    {

        UILabel *mijnlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];

        mijnlabel.text = @"Loremipsum";
        [self.view addSubview:mijnlabel];
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: I didn't had any problems so far. But i am fairly new to objective-c and didn't know how to get the value returned from the php script and use it in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your labels will all display at the same position, you are right to do so by sending `[self.view addSubview:mijnlabel];` to the view.

You have to be careful on these few things :

1. The way you right your loop, use as the counter, another variable rather than the value you parsed from the string.
2. Don't forget to release the `UILabel`you initialized just after adding it to the view.
3. Send `viewDidLoad` first to the super view.

So your might result to :

```
// first
[super viewDidLoad];

...

NSString *aStr = [[[NSString alloc]
                   initWithData:urlData
                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease]; 
int labelsCount = [aStr intValue];
status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",labelsCounts];
// another way, in order to display the label under each other
// this will display labelsCount labels
int i;
for(i = 0; i < labelsCount; i++) {
    CGFloat yCoord = i * 100;
    UILabel *mijnlabel = [[UILabel alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, yCoord, 200, 100)];
    mijnlabel.text = @"Loremipsum";
    [self.view addSubview:mijnlabel];
    [mijnLabel release];
}
```

Comment: And how do i display all the labels under each other?

Comment: The initializer takes a `CGRect`to define the frame of the `UILabel`s. Here you are creating labels at (50, 100) and width = 200, height = 100. so for example you could use the counter. I will update the answer